# The ways to say someone has had ear or umbilicus / umbilical piercings

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

What a native speaker would usually say to indicate someone has had ear piercings? My translations are as below, but I'm not sure if they are natural:

> She has pierced her (ear lobe / umbilicus).
>
> She has a piercing on her (ear lobe / umbilicus).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say:

> He has pierced ears.
>
> Are your ears pierced?
>
> How old were you when you pierced your ears?

and

> She got her belly button pierced.
>
> Did your belly-button piercing hurt?
>
> I'm thinking of getting my navel pierced.
>
> I like your navel piercing.

Of the two examples you mentioned, the second one: "She has a piercing on her ___" sounds very unnatural to me.

For the first example: "She has pierced her ears" sounds less natural than "She has pierced ears" or "She pierced her ears", depending on what you're trying to convey.

Also, I would never expect a native speaker to say "umbilicus" outside of medical/academic contexts. In fact, this is the first time I've seen that word used before.

Comment: Agreed.  "She has pierced ears" focuses on the state of her ears, which is what we're usually interested in.  "She has pierced her ears" focuses on the action of piercing them.